# Emacs first boot won't install all packages from package-selected-packages

Tags: emacs, installation, elpa

I've got this in my `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

(setq package-archives '(("ELPA"  . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
             ("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
             ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             ("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;; Bootstrapping use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))

(use-package use-package
  :config
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t))
```

As far as I understand, this should be good to install all the packaged listed in

```
'(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (org org-plus-contrib org-ref techela tuareg haskell-mode gnuplot gnuplot-mode helm-ispell ac-ispell paredit ox-tufte auctex json org-grep iedit wgrep helm geiser slime-company company-jedi zzz-to-char rainbow-delimiters avy ivy projectile twittering-mode zerodark-theme pretty-mode flycheck-clang-analyzer flycheck-irony flycheck yasnippet company-c-headers company-shell company-irony irony irony-mode company-lua mark-multiple expand-region popup-kill-ring dmenu ido-vertical-mode ido-vertical ox-html5slide centered-window-mode htmlize ox-twbs diminish erc-hl-nicks symon rainbow-mode switch-window dashboard smex company sudo-edit emms magit org-bullets hungry-delete beacon linum-relative spaceline fancy-battery exwm use-package)))
```

which is inside my `custom-set-variables`. However, when I do a first-time, clean (no existing `elpa/` directory) startup of Emacs reading this `init.el`, not all of the packages are gotten and installed. But then I can do a `package-install-selected-packages` and, Emacs reports that it doesn't have anything in `package-selected-packages`. Looking at the variable confirms this. What could be going wrong? An older "working" version of this (with existing `elpa/` directory) responds oddly to `package-install-selected-packages`, wanting to install e.g., `auctex` and some nine other packages that the package code above apparently isn't seeing or dealing with. I'm baffled as to why `package-selected-packages` seems to be so flaky for me. I'm assuming my older `.emacs.d` with the existing `elpa/` has install info that is "working around" this failing `package-selected-packages` situation.

Comment: Why are you surprised `package-install-selected-packages` wants to install auctex, since it's among the packages listed in your `package-selected-packages`?  Also, if `package-selected-packages` is empty, it means there's a problem in your `~/.emacs` that ends up not interpreting the `package-selected-packages` setting the way you intended.  Without showing this part, there's nothing we can do (whereas all the use-package and package-archives settings you do show are basically irrelevant since they don't really affect `package-install-selected-packages`).

Comment: I need to know why the first code block above is not taking the `package-selected-packages` list and installing ALL of the listed packages on the first start-up. I've hacked "Uncle Dave's Emacs" (https://github.com/daedreth/UncleDavesEmacs) and once you get rid of some of his bugs, it goes out to a `config.org` right after the first stuff above -- and starts installing packages, but, again, seemingly NOT by what is listed right below in `custom-set-variables`'s `package-selected-packages`. The `package` code should read what's in the package list and install all those packages -- but it's not.

Comment: As I mentioned in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48369, that code block is *not* supposed to install those packages.  When you want to install them you have to explicitly call `package-install-selected-packages`.  As a general rule, Emacs tries to never make network connections unless there is a very explicit request to do so from the user.

Comment: Good, but where should I place `package-install-selected-packages` in the op top code block? And why isn't `(use-package use-package  :config  (setq use-package-always-ensure t))` good enough? I still fear something's wrong with my code. I thought this was a basic thing with package, i.e., if it isn't installed and it's mentioned in `package-selected-packages`, go get it and install it.

Comment: It needs to come after the setting of `package-selected-packages` and after you have set the `package-archives` (otherwise it can't know which packages to install nor where to fetch them from).  As for the `use-package` question, you'll have to ask someone who knows about `use-package`, but `use-package` was not designed together with `package.el`, so `use-package` has no reason to pay attention to `package.el` settings like `package-selected-packages`.

Comment: "I thought this was a basic thing with package, i.e., if it isn't installed and it's mentioned in package-selected-packages, go get it and install it." -- Is there a particular reason you thought that?  Looking at `C-h v package-selected-packages` I can see nothing to suggest any such behaviour.